# javascript callback parameter undefined

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm new to using callback functions and struggling trying to hook some up through jquery that are to be called when certain ui elements are changed.  This is a very simplified example of what I'm doing.  If I call the e.SetBorderWidth then it passes 10 into the function correctly.  However, if I try to use the callback the SetBorderWidth is getting undefined.  Any idea why and what I need to change?  Thanks.

javascript code----

```
element = {
    border: {
        width:0
    },

    SetBorderWidth : function(newWidth){
        this.border.width = newWidth;
    }
};

elementChild = function(){
    padding: 0
};

elementChild.prototype = element;


var e = new elementChild();

var callback = e.SetBorderWidth;

function SetWidth(){
    e.SetBorderWidth(10);
    alert(e.border.width);

    callback.call(10);
    alert(e.border.width);
}
```

and the html code

```
<input type="button" onclick="SetWidth();" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do `callback(10)`; adding `.call` passes `10` as the context (`this` variable) instead of the argument.

Comment: I agree with the missing context, but should it be `this`. It is really hard to say what should be passed as the execution context inside the function `SetWidth`.

Comment: I think the context should `e` than `this`.

Comment: I changed it to just callback and then changed this.border.width = newWidth to e.border.width = newWidth.  That worked but this isn't quite what I was hoping for.  It seems like I'm then locked into having to know the variable name for the instance of this object.  Is there another way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: In this example it might not make a lot of sense but as I said, this is an extremely simplified version of a larger problem I'm working on.  In my current situation I have a variable with the function that needs called by another element on the page.  That element gives the function a value which needs to be applied to the property of the object variable.  I have many elements that interact with this one object variable, each calling their own callback functions to set properties of the object.  This is just a quick example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: nevermind, I think I figured it out.  I changed callback(10) to callback(e, 10) and then changed the SetBorderWidth method to SetBorderWidth : function(obj, newWidth){ obj.border.width = newWidth;}